# Secure passwords with jenkins on an untrusted hosting provider

Tags: security, jenkins, hosting

I have a jenkins installation on a hosting provider that I do not trust. How can I secure it against the hosting provider?

I've been reading about Credentials Plugin - https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc and there is a sentence

```
If a non-trusted user can gain access to the files in the JENKINS_HOME/secrets directory, then it is game over.
```

The hosting provider has access to the JENKINS_HOME/secrets folder so I can not secure passwords using credentials-plugin. At least this is how I understand it.

My question: What should I do to store credentials on drive encrypted and to have a password provided when starting jenkins for example, or when logging in? Store everything encrypted on drive and have the password in memory for example?

'change the hosting provider since you don't trust them' is not the kind of answer that would help me. I generally think that everything stored on hosting providers should be kept encrypted, but that discussion is also for another time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem for now. It has certain limitations but at least the password is not stores in secrets and not available to the hosting provider. I would really welcome comments for improvements. Again what I really want is to make the password available to certain builds but to store this password out of reach for people with access to the filesystem and the machine

Certain jobs at jenkins depend on password stored in ENV variables. Jenkins should continue working without this password, only the specific build should fail if passwords are not provided. These are for example db backups builds.

The password could be stored in the jenkins/secrets but this means the hosting provider will have access to this passwords. This is not desired. The passwords are provided as ENV variables when jenkins starts.

To do this they must be added to /etc/default/jenkins and added to the deamon arguments in /etc/init.d/jenkins

Add the password to /etc/default/jenkins with

```
SPECIAL_PASSWORD=123
```

The password is processes by /etc/init.d/jenkins and added to DAEMON_ARGS in the following way:

```
if [ -n "$SPECIAL_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "Using SPECIAL_PASSWORD provided by /etc/default/jenkins"
    DAEMON_ARGS="$DAEMON_ARGS --env=SPECIAL_PASSWORD=$SPECIAL_PASSWORD"
fi
```

This makes SPECIAL_PASSWORD available to jenkins when it starts. The password is visible in the SystemInfo tab in jenkins as an ENV variable and could be used by jenkins build jobs.

Storing the password in the /etc/default/jenkins is not desired. This makes it again available to the hosting provider.

That's why I've implemented the following scripts that 
1. ask for a password
2. adds the SPECIAL_PASSWORD to /etc/default/jenkins
3. restarts jenkins
4. restores the /etc/default/jenkins to the original version without the password

```
#!/bin/bash
# The script requies passwords for starting jenkins and places this password
# in the jenkins env. It then restarts jenkins after which the file is returned
# to the original 

read -s -p "Enter SPECIAL_PASSWORD: " SPECIAL_PASSWORD

cp /etc/default/jenkins /etc/default/jenkins.bck

echo "SPECIAL_PASSWORD=$SPECIAL_PASSWORD" >> /etc/default/jenkins
echo "Contents of the jenkins env"

service jenkins restart

cp /etc/default/jenkins.bck /etc/default/jenkins
```

Limitations:
1. The password for a brief moment of time is available in /etc/default/jenkins.
2. The password is available in plain text as an ENV variable for the whole jenkins.